# Unable to save data to a Database importing a CSV file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have been trying to import a .csv file on my Ruby on Rails application in order to store the data about a Peak, but failed using different methods. The application redirects to the root_url but the database remains empty. The program seems to work, at least it does not provide errors, but no data is imported into the database. This how my peaks_controller looks like:

```
class PeaksController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @peak = Peak.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
        @peaks = Peak.all
    end

    def import
        Peak.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Peaks imported."

    end

    def new
        @peak = Peak.new
    end

    def create
        @peak = Peak.new(peak_params)

        if @peak.save
            redirect_to @peak
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end



    private
        def peak_params
            params.require(:peak).permit(:name, :altitude, :prominence, :isolation, :key_col, :source, :accessibility, :land_use, :hazard, :longitude, :latitude)
        end
end
```

This is my peak.rb class:

```
class Peak < ApplicationRecord


validates :altitude, presence: true
validates :prominence, presence: true
validates :isolation, presence: true
validates :key_col, presence: true
validates :source, presence: true
validates :accessibility, presence: true
validates :land_use, presence: true

validates :longitude, presence: true
validates :latitude, presence: true



#non funziona

def self.import(file)

    csv = CSV.parse(File.read(file), :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|

    p = Peak.new


    p.id = row['id'] 
    p.name = row['Name']
    p.altitude = row['Altitude']
    p.prominence = row['Prominence']
    p.isolation = row['Isolation']
    p.key_col = row['Key_col']
    p.source = row['Source']
    p.accessibility = row['Accessibility']
    p.land_use = row['Land_use']
    p.hazard = row['Hazard']
    p.longitude = row['x']
    p.latitude = row['y']
    p.save
    end
end

end
```

That just does not return anything, so it does not import anything into my database, I have also tried the following import method:

```
def self.import(file)

    csv = CSV.parse(File.read(file), :headers => false)
    csv.each do |row|

    Peak.create!(row.to_h)
    end
end
```

This is how my database looks like:

```
    class CreatePeaks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :peaks do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.decimal :altitude
        t.decimal :prominence
        t.decimal :isolation
        t.decimal :key_col
        t.string :source
        t.decimal :accessibility
        t.string :land_use
        t.string :hazard
        t.decimal :longitude
        t.decimal :latitude
    end
  end

end
```

[And this are the headerds of the .csv file][:1]

I have inclunded "require 'csv'" on my application.rb so the application reads a csv file.

I have also tried to remove the 'id' column from the file and tried with the "row.to_h" but it did not change anything, still can't import the values onto the database.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly is not working, what happens instead? Is there an error message? What does it tell?

Comment: The application redirects to the root_url but the database remains empty. So it is like the method does not give any error, but it does not do what it should do, as it should add a record to the table Peak.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part when doing a mass import is error handling - of which you're doing none. So all those calls to save the records could be failing and you're none the wiser.

You basically have two options:

## 1. Strict

Wrap the import in a transaction and roll back if any of the records are invalid. This avoids leaving the job half done.

```
class Peak < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def self.import(file)  
    csv = CSV.parse(File.read(file), :headers => true)
    transaction do
      csv.map do |row|
        create!(
          id: row['id'],
          name: row['Name'],
          altitude: row['Altitude'],
          prominence: row['Prominence'],
          isolation: row['Isolation'],
          key_col: row['Key_col'],
          source: row['Source'],
          accessibility: row['Accessibility'],
          land_use: row['Land_use'],
          hazard: row['Hazard'],
          longitude: row['x'],
          latitude: row['y']
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
class PeaksController < ApplicationController
  def import
    begin 
      @peaks = Peak.import(params[:file])
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Peaks imported."
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      redirect_to 'somewhere/else', error: "Import failed."
    end
  end
end
```

### 2. Lax

In some scenarios you might want to do lax processing and just keep on going even if some records fail to import. This can be combined with a form that lets the user correct the invalid values.

```
class Peak < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def self.import(file)  
    csv = CSV.parse(File.read(file), :headers => true)
    peaks = csv.map do |row|
      create_with(
        name: row['Name'],
        altitude: row['Altitude'],
        prominence: row['Prominence'],
        isolation: row['Isolation'],
        key_col: row['Key_col'],
        source: row['Source'],
        accessibility: row['Accessibility'],
        land_use: row['Land_use'],
        hazard: row['Hazard'],
        longitude: row['x'],
        latitude: row['y']
      ).find_or_create_by(id: row['id'])
    end
  end
end
```

```
class PeaksController < ApplicationController
  def import
    @peaks = Peak.import(params[:file])
    @invalid_peaks = @peaks.reject {|p| p.persisted? }
    if @invalid_peaks.none?
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Peaks imported."
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "import failed"
      render 'some_kind_of_form'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, as your explanation, the first failed while the second worked with some empty fields. Now I have an other question. When I run "rails console" to check into the database, I don't see the data that should have been imported, is that because there are some invalid fields, so it can't be saved, or is there something else I would need to add to save on the database?

Comment: Its most like due to invalid fields. And in the first case its designed to fail if any of the input is invalid - which is often desirable when doing batch importing as you don't want a half imported file. Instead of using the console - use byebug or pry to add a breakpoint inside the controller and inspect `@invalid_peaks.first.errors.full_messages`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have now fixed the error which was caused by misspelling the row in the csv file, and now the import works as I have everything in my database. Thanks again